# How to set the preview flag for google cloud delpoyment manager deployments.insert() api in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to preview a configuration before creating it using the Java client libraries for Google Cloud Deployment Manager like shown below.

```
DeploymentManager deploymentManagerService = createDeploymentManagerService();
Deployment requestBody = new Deployment();
requestBody.setName(deployment);
TargetConfiguration config = new TargetConfiguration();
ConfigFile configFile = new ConfigFile();

File file = new File("C:\\gcp-work\\two-vms.yaml");
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
String content =  new String(encoded);
configFile.setContent(content);
config.setConfig(configFile);
requestBody.setTarget(config);

Deployments.Insert insReq = deploymentManagerService.deployments().insert(PROJECT_NAME, requestBody);
Operation oprtn =  insReq.execute();
```

For the insert I'm not finding a way to set the preview flag.
The [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/reference/latest/deployments/insert) on shows that there is an optional query parameter. I'm wondering how to set it from a Java client like mine shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DeploymentManager.deployments.instert class java doc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/deploymentmanager/v2/java/latest/) may help you with the possible actions.

My educated guess is you need to call this before execute():

> insReq.setPreview(true);